# Solution to cubic inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do I find the solutions to this equation?  $$(3x^3)-(14x^2)-(5x) \leq 0$$

Comment: Hint: x = 2 is a root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Find the roots of the cubic equation $3x^3-14x^2-5x=0$.
$$
\begin{align*}
x(3x^2-14x-5)&=0\\
x(3x+1)(x-5)&=0\\
x&=0\quad\text{or}\\
x&=-\frac{1}{3}\quad\text{or}\\
x&=5
\end{align*}
$$
**Step 2.** Draw a sign table for $P=3x^3-14x^2-5x$.

[image]

**Step 3:** From your sign table, you can see that for $x\in(-\infty,-\frac{1}{3}]\cup[0,5]$, $P\leq0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Factorise $(3x^3)-(14x^2)-(5x)$ and find the signs of the quadratic polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

$3x^{3}-14x^{2}-5x=x(3x^{2}-14x-5)=x(3x+1)(x-5)$.

So the zeroes are at $x=0$, $x=\frac{-1}{3}$ and at $x=5$.

For $x>5$ then the polynomial is positive since the above factorization is a product of positive numbers. For $0<x<5$ the polynomial is negative since the above factorization is a product of two positive numbers and a negative one. For $\frac{-1}{3}<x<0$ the polynomial is positive by similar reasoning. For $x<\frac{-1}{3}$ the polynomial is negative.

So the polynomial is non-positive for $\{x\le\frac{-1}{3}\}\cup\{0\le x\le5\}$.